# EEGLab: Number of ICA components

Tags: matlab, pca, eeglab

I have an EEG acquired through 238 channels. When I decide to perform ICA, I have no idea about how many independent components I should obtain. If I have understood well, when I perform ICA the number of channels is equal to the number of independent components, so in my specific case I think I should have 238 components.

In EEGLab toolbox, in the window appeared by click on `run ICA` command I set `runica` for the algorithm to use and 'extended', 1 , 'pca', 238  in command line options.

Is it correct? Thanks to everyone.

P.S. I have already read other answers on ICA, but I am a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

The number of components doesn't have to be the same as the number of recording channels. Increasing the number of components will decrease the speed of the computations.

According to the EEGLab [manual](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/Chapter_09:_Decomposing_Data_Using_ICA):

> When the number of channels (N) is large (>>32) then a very large
>   amount of data may be required to find N components. When insufficient
>   data are available, then using the 'pca' option to jader.m to find
>   fewer than N components may be the only good option.

You might want to read this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/how-do-i-select-the-number-of-components-for-independent-components-analysis) on CrossValidated.

Answer (score -1):

I typically use N components which is suitable even for large EEG datasets. I have experience with 256 channels, then pop_runica where N components are 256. No big deal. It only take a time to be computed, but you can parallelize your process and put it on computing cluster.